# changing font and color size based on cell values

Tags: excel, vba

This is very different to what I have found in searches using this question.

I want to be able to change font size and color (RGB) based on cell values for a range. This would allow users to customize a form (size and colour of headings, general text, etc.)

For font size, this, below, works perfectly, but it doesn't work for font colour unless I specify the colour in the code.

Cell B1 contains the font size, **12**, and cell B2 contains **255, 255, 0**

```
Sub fontsizecolor ()

Dim rgb2 As String
rgb2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B2").Text

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
 .Font.Size = Range("B1")
        '.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)  **<---- this works**
 
 .Font.Color = RGB(rgb2)
 
 
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: [`RGB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rgb-function) expects 3 numeric arguments. You are passing it one string. You need to either parse the string into 3 arguments, perhaps using `Split`, or put the 3 numeric values in 3 different cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As BigBen mentions you need to provide 3 arguments to `RGB` and the `Split` function can achieve that for you.

In the below example we take the text from B2, split it and store the elements into an array. Then we simply feed those elements into `RGB`:

```
Sub fontsizecolor()

    Dim rgb2, rgbArray() As String
    
    rgb2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B2").Text
    rgbArray = Split(rgb2, ",") ' split string on ","
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
        .Font.Size = Range("B1")
        .Font.Color = RGB(rgbArray(0), rgbArray(1), rgbArray(2)) ' feed array elements as arguments
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thought I'd also point out that you can skip storing the results of `Split` into an array and just use `Split` directly in `RGB` like so: `.Font.Color = RGB(Split(rgb2, ",")(0), Split(rgb2, ",")(1), Split(rgb2, ",")(2))`. I feel this looks a little messy but that may just be me - both approaches work though

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Works perfectly. Thanks you BigBen and adb. I was going crazy trying to find an online solution for this. Every online search only throws up solutions regarding changing colors etc for the cell itself based on the cells value. (Eg if value is > 10 turn Blue, etc)

Comment: Happy to help @Leonard